# Is `arc4random` family of functions thread safe?

Tags: ios, macos, unix, random, cryptography

I care especially about iOS and OS X.

If not, what are the possible replacements with cryptographic quality of randomness?

Comment: What is your thread safe concern? That is how would not being thread safe  cause a problem? That the bytes might get mixed? How would this cause the results to be less random?

Comment: @zaph: Race condition leads to *undefined behavior*, which includes all kinds of weird magic. One case I could imagine is that two threads get exactly the same random number. If that is the initialization vector for a AES-CTR, that completely defeats the security guarantee.

Comment: @zaph Were it not thread-safe, not only could it be undefined behaviour to call a non-thread-safe PRNG from multiple threads simultaneously, but it could also seriously mess up its internal state and break the randomness of all future results. Also, if the PRNG didn't suffer from this, it might still return the same result for simultaneous calls, which would totally mess up any kind of multi-threaded Monte Carlo approximation, for example… (Although in such use it is often better to have a separate PRNG instance, each seeded differently, for each thread to avoid the need to synchronise.)

Comment: For instance, even if we assume that read/write of the PRNG's internal state is atomic, the typical function would first read the internal state, manipulate it to produce the next state, write that to the internal state, and then return the result based on the state. Without synchronisation two calls could both read the same internal state if the second one entered before the first one had time to write the next state; they would produce the same result, which would make for a very non-random pattern when repeated frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `arc4random`, `arc4random_uniform`, `arc4random_buf`, `arc4random_stir`, and `arc4random_addrandom` are thread-safe as they are.

You can see this in the [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.10.1/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c), and it has also been confirmed by Apple's developer relations personnel (but I can't find the link at the moment).